# Vertically center numbers in table

Tags: tables

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn,ragged2e}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{,}{#1}}
\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
 \centering
  \begin{tabular}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{4.4cm} d{2.1} d{2.1} d{2.1} d{2.1} d{2.1} d{2.1} d{2.1} d{2.1} d{2.1}}
   \toprule
    \mc{{\AA}rstal} & \mc{1997} & \mc{1998} & \mc{1999} & \mc{2000} & \mc{2001} & \mc{2002} & \mc{2003} & \mc{2004} & \mc{2005} \\[1ex]
    Antal passagerer i mio., som lufthavnen kan betjene
                    & 17.1 & 17.8 & 19.9 & 22.7 & 22.7 & 25.2 & 25.2 & 25.2 & 28.0 \\
    Forventet {\aa}rligt passagertal i mio.
                    & 16.6 & 17.4 & 18.2 & 19.0 & 20.0 & 20.9 & 22.0 & 23.1 & 24.2 \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

How do I vertically center the numbers relativt to the blocks of text in the first column? Now, the numbers are vertically aligned at the top of the ``double lines''.

Comment: related:  [How to vertically align multiline column](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103115/579)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `m{4.4cm}` instead of `p{4.4cm}` for the first column.

[`dcolumn`](http://ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn) loads [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) as part of its required packages. The latter supports the `m`-column format. From the [`array` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/array.pdf):

> **`m{width}`** Defines a column of width `width`. Every entry will be centered in proportion to the rest of the line. It is somewhat like `\parbox{width}`.

[image]

Comment: +1 and have my image as you beat me by a second or two:-)

Comment: Great; thank you! That was easy. `:)`